# Can someone make a photograph of the original Apple 1 Integer BASIC cassette?

Tags: apple-ii, basic

I'm wondering if anyone here has an original Integer BASIC cassette and might be willing to upload an image of it to the wiki commons? There's a serious lack of imagery in the article in en.wiki, and this seems like a reasonable way to spruce it up.

Comment: It might be worth specifying photographic image (of the tape etc) if that's what you mean. When I skim read your question, I assumed binary image, as did Raffzahn when he wrote his answer. Also, the title is "copy of the original", but I think you mean "the original", if that's what you want a photograph of. Mincing words, I know, but consider those for whom English is not their first language.

Answer (score 17):

*Oops. Rereading the questions body makes me think that it's not asking about a copy of the BASIC, as the title implies, but for a photographic image of the cassette it was distributed on.*

- This [Youtube-video of Core Cohen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMikZe_FxJQ) shows what might be a pre-production cassette.
- Michael Steil's [Pagetable](https://www.pagetable.com/?p=32) holds what seems to be an [image of the production version](http://www.weihenstephan.org/%7Emichaste/temp/pagetable/apple1basic.jpg) (Note the green, non-bitten Apple logo from before the multi coloured logo was introduced).

  Go an ask, I can't imagine him denying usage for the Wiki.

---

[Integer BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_BASIC) had no source code - at least none as one might assume today. Wozniak did code it into a notebook and hand translated it to binary, which he entered using his 256 byte [WOZMON](https://steckschwein.de/2018/07/22/wozmon-a-memory-monitor-in-256-bytes/).

- Eric Smith did a [disassembly in 2003](http://www.brouhaha.com/%7Eeric/retrocomputing/apple/apple1/basic/).
- Jeff Tranter [used that](http://jefftranter.blogspot.com/2012/05/source-code-for-apple-1-basic.html) disassembly in 2012 to create a [CA65 compatible version](https://github.com/jefftranter/6502/tree/master/asm/a1basic)
- Eric Smith also turned it into an [assembly source](https://github.com/brouhaha/a1basic/) in 2020

Answer (score 17):

There's an excellent collection of Apple cassette images on the [Brutal Deluxe](https://www.brutaldeluxe.fr/projects/cassettes/apple/) web site, including [these images](https://www.brutaldeluxe.fr/projects/cassettes/apple/a1_cassettes.jpeg) of Apple 1 tapes.  In most cases, photographs and file data are available.